# Displaying DIV dynamically on button click using Jquery

Tags: jquery, jsp

I have DIV which is a dynamic one, within each dynamic DIV I have a button, on mouse over or on click of button I need to display a modal/div next to the button.  Something like below,

[Earth Quake is one scenario which has selected and similarly we can have multiple scenarios for each scenario there will be load preset button for Parameters and Configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kLFpN.png)

[My implementation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GaXMm.png)

Comment: Since I am new to Jquery I have done it with Modal, but I could not position the modal next to the button. IO have tried giving position of the div to the modal, then also I could not achieved it. Kindly help me here.

Comment: Are you using Boostrap modal?

Comment: Yes, Im using Boostrap modal.

Comment: update your question with your code

Answer (score 0):

Instead of a modal you could use a [Bootstrap Popover](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/popovers/). The description on w3schools:

> The Popover plugin is similar to tooltips; it is a pop-up box that appears when the user clicks on an element. The difference is that the popover can contain much more content.

Since you want your modal to appear at your button, this seems to be what you are looking for.